# can i make dynamic list of countries and cities in javascript+html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dynamic list of cities, and each country has its own dynamic list of cities.

Now I'm checking the postal code column with Javascript and I am trying to create a function that will do the next search, when I choose `Netherlands`, it lets me use other characters in the postalcode, but until now I don't see any success.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

---

**HTML:**

```
<tr>
<td>
<p class="RegTextLine">Your Postalcode </p>
<input type="text" name="postalcode" id="postalcode" class="columnstyle" placeholder="Enter your postal code" onchange="postcode('postalcode','Country')"/>
</td>
</tr>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function postcode(code, holland) {
    var code = document.getElementById(code);
    var holland = document.getElementById(holland);
    var dcount=0;
    var charcount=0;
    var jcount=0;



    if (holland.value == "netherland") {
        for (var i = 0; i <= code.length; i++){
             if (code.value.charAt(i) >= '0' && code.value.charAt(i) <= '9')
            dcount++;
        else if (code.value.charAt(i) >= 'a' && code.value.charAt(i) <= 'z')
            charcount++;
        else if (code.value.charAt(i) >= 'A' && code.value.charAt(i) <= 'Z')
            charcount++;
            else
            jcount++;
     }
     if (jcount!=0)
         alert("This symbol is not allowed");

    else 
        alert("holland is good");
    }
    if (holland.value != "netherland") {
        for (var i = 0; i <= code.length; i++) {
            if (code.value.charAt(i) >= '0' && code.value.charAt(i) <= '9')
                dcount++;
            else
                jcount++;
        }
        if (jcount!=0)
            alert("use only digits");
        else
            alert("regular postalcode is work fine");
    }   
}
```

Comment: Do You get an error? Does this code run?

Comment: that the thing no error occur or any alert

Comment: Put an `alert` in the first line of Your function. Does it show?

Comment: no and i really dont know why , i mean i write to function start workf onclick, i even try to change it to onsumbit and onchange but nothing .

Comment: You are passing the id in but you don't actually specify an id in your html. So that will cause a problem as the code variable won't get set

Comment: still nothing and if somebody can explain me what the real diffrent between name and id? but if it a big topic just skip it .

Comment: guys just updating  that i got some problem in the begging, the function not even run , i know it because i try to remove all the code from the function and only give it an alert by default but nothing happend.

Comment: guys some changes was done, like i remove the inner html because i just realize i dont even need it, and make some alert to focus on the problem: the function run now and the loops work fine, but no matter what the jcount refuses grow up why is that?

Comment: * no count grow up, even if i put condition on  else like: else if (dcount>0) and then alert ("dcount");    , the condition successfuly executed and dcount==0 , what the hellll ,

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code:

```
<input type="text" name="postalcode" class="columnstyle" placeholder="Enter your postal code" onchange="postalcode(this.id,'Country')"/>
```

It's wrong because the 'Country' parameter in the function postalcode is unclear
 This input type is text, so it's also invalid to get the this.id, instead this is the solution I recommend:
1st) Make an select option to let the user choose the country:

```
<label>choose your country</label>
<select name="country onchange="userCountry(this.value)">
<option value="country_a">a</option>
<option value="country_b">b</option>
</select>
```

2nd) create input for user to type in postal code with pattern of their country:
2a) Create function create the pattern of the postal code:

```
function userCountry(country) {
   switch (country) {
      case a:
      limitLength = 6;
      // you could set up your regex for input validation
      regExp = /\d{3,6}/;
      break;
      case b:
      limitLength = 8;
      break;
      // etc.
   };
   document.getElementById("postalCode").setAttribute("maxlength",limitLength);
};
// here is the input in html for user to input the postal code
<input type="text" name="user_postalcode" id="postalCode" onkeyup="validationCode()"/>
// validation the input, only necessary if you have regexp
function validationCode() {
   var invalidCode = /[^\d]+/g; // wrong pattern you make your own, in this case, all characters beside digital character will be considered invalid.
   if (this.value.match(regExp) == null) { // check if it's wrong
      this.value.replace(invalidCode,""); // replace all invalid code with space, so it will remain only valid code
   };
};
```

I hope this helps, I've tried to understand your problem , this is come with what I comprehended from your question.

Comment: i dont really get what you mean by this "unclear
This input type is text" , but in my other function like in dynamic list i got in html two selects and in Country select i did exacly like here (this.id,'city') and all work fine maybe if you can explain a bit more what you mean by "unclear
This input type is text" it would be more clear to me. and thank you for helping me.